# Which modifies which in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

Please tell me which modifies which in the second sentence.

It is evident that there are two modifiers in the first sentence, "not" and "in the least". The words or phrases in round brackets are modifiers, and those in square brackets are the elements modified.

But things seem to get difficult in the second sentence. Is my grammatical analysis of the sentence correct?

1/ Gibbie was [(not) [disappointed]] (in the least).

2/ Gibbie was ((not) [in the least]) [disappointed].

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to remember with "not in the least" / "not in the slightest" that there is an implicit noun that is omitted. What we are really saying is something like "not in the least ***amount***" or "not in the slightest ***degree***", but the accepted form of the phrase omits that noun.
So, I would argue, "the least" modifies the implicit noun (e.g. "amount"). The "not" modifies "disappointed" and the adverbial phrase "in the least [amount/degree/...]" doesn't really *modify* "not disappointed"; it *qualifies* it.

Answer (score 0):

It's is the same for 1 and 2.  In both *in the least* modifies *disappointed*.  If sets a low threshold for what is considered disappointing.

It may seem like *not* should be doing more, but it simply negates.  However, if you remove it the sentence sounds weird.

This isn't because of a grammatical error. It's because "not in the least" is an idiom (one that doesn't care if the word order is like 1 or 2).  Without the *not* it's no longer idiomatic.  That's why "Gibbie was disappointed in the least" sounds so odd.

Comment: Does this mean the sentences should be analyzed like below?

Comment: Gibbie was (not) [[disappointed] (in the least)].

Comment: Gibbie was ((not) [in the least]) [disappointed].

Comment: Not only the phrase ''in the least" but also the negative "not" can be displaced without a change in meaning - like these sentences:  <Neither> of us was in the least disappointed. I have <not> been disappointed in the least in my expectations.

Comment: Well yes, but honestly, if you wanted to, you could also diagram them as *Gibble was [(not) [disappointed]] (in the least)* and *Gibbie was (not in the least) [disappointed].*

Comment: If there are many possible diagrams to the same sentence, then there might be something inherently amiss about this and other similar diagramming approaches, which are linear, while the sentence structure is sometimes non-linear, when some elements may be displaced or even transformed using a different structure ("neither of" instead of "not"')?

Comment: I know this sounds strange, but  is it correct to interpret "in the least" as the modifier of "not", rather than the phrase modified by "not"?

Comment: He was ([not] (in the least)) [worried].

Comment: He was [(not) [worried]] (in the slightest).

Comment: In this way there is only one diagram to each sentence, which looks consistent and better.

Comment: @Xuan Huy Since "not" follows the auxiliary verb "was", the sentence is most likely to be interpreted as a case of primary verbal negation, i.e. "not" modifies "was". The non-affirmative adjunct _in the least_ can only modify the AdjP "disappointed", since it explains the degree to which Gibbie was not disappointed.

Comment: That makes sense. However, please tell me if the negative meaning applies globally in both sentences. If the modifier "in the least" can be preposed, which is normally very unusual, then is there any change in meaning?

Comment: The end result meaning remains the same in every ordering presented here and every approach to diagramming.  Only way I see to change the meaning is to take *least* to be a noun. English does not permit a diagramming system that reliably produces a 1 to 1 relationship between sentence construction and diagram.  The language is too wild and wooly.  A diagram shows you how someone chose to read a sentence.  It doesn't show you the only possible way the author could have meant the sentence to be read.

Comment: @Xuan Huy Yes, the verbal negation reading would apply to both your examples. The adjunct _in the least_ works fine pre- or post- "disappointed" with no change in meaning. It's not at all unusual for it to be used as a pre-head modifier in examples like yours.

Comment: It seems, from the comments, that the OP hasn't fully understood the answer, so let me convert it into diagrams of the sort used in the question: (not)[[disappointed](in the least)] and (not)[(in the least)[disappointed]].